# C++ style polymorphic output in Java

Tags: java, c++, file, logging, outputstream

In C++ I used to save myself a lot of time by passing around `std::ostream` objects. Instead of, for instance, hard coding all my data logging to `std::cout`, I would make `std::cout` a default parameter to the function like so.

```
void func(std::ostream os = std::cout) {
    ...
    os<<"Something";
    ...
 }
```

That way if I wanted to print the same data to a file later, I could do that no problem by calling `func(file)` where `file` was a `std::ofstream`.

My issue is that in Java, there doesn't seem to be any unified way of performing I/O. I need to print exactly the same set of data to the console and to a file. What's the most succinct way I can do that? If I can do it polymorphically like I used to with `std::ostream` and `std::ofstream`, that would be my preference, as that's what I'm used to.

Comment: so in java you have good logging frameworks. if your purpose is logging, why invent your own wheel. use for instance slf4j log your things and do a logging configuration which gives your even more flexibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `PrintStream` can take a filename as a constructor argument, I would simplify Paul's answer this way:

```
void someMethod(PrintStream ps) {
    ps.print(...);
    ps.format(....);
    // etc
}

someMethod(System.out);                           // Output to console
someMethod(new PrintStream("file.out", "UTF-8")); // Output to a file
```

[Documentation here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It's concise, and it mirrors the mechanic I'm used to perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out` is a `PrintStream`, writing to files is performed via `FileOutputStream` in java. The common super-class is `OutputStream`. Since `OutputStream` would only write `byte[]`, `byte` and a few other primitives, you'll have to use a wrapper-class though.

```
class OutputWrapper{
    private OutputStream os;

    public OutputWrapper(OutputStream os){
        this.os = os;
    }

    public void print(String s){
        os.write(s.getBytes());
    }

    public void flush(){
        os.flush();
    }

    ...
}

void someMethod(OutputStream os){
    OutputWrapper out = new OutputWrapper(os);
    out.print("Hello, World!");
    out.flush();
}

someMethod(System.out);//print to console
someMethod(new FileOutputStream("somefile.txt"));//print to file
```

I've left out error-handling here, and the example is really basic, but that's the closest you'll get to the behaviour described above.

Answer (score 0):

In your case **StringBuffer** class in java will serve the purpose. Its primary operations are append and insert methods, which are overloaded so as to accept data of any type.
To know more you can refer to [StringBuffer_reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html)